# Ссылка на тип класса (Java)

Tags: java, многопоточность

Сразу покажу код, потом вопрос:

```
class Callme{

    void call(String msg){
        System.out.print("[" + msg);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }catch (InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("Прервано!");
        }
        System.out.println("]");
    }
}

class Caller implements Runnable{

    String msg;
    Callme target;
    Thread t;

    public Caller (Callme targ, String s){

        target = targ;
        msg = s;

        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    public void run(){
        synchronized (target){
            target.call(msg);
        }
    }
}

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Callme target = new Callme();

        Caller ob1 = new Caller(target, "Один");
        Caller ob2 = new Caller(target, "Два");
        Caller ob3 = new Caller(target, "Три");

        try {
            ob1.t.join();
            ob2.t.join();
            ob3.t.join();
        }catch (InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("Прервано!");
        }
    }
}
```

Изучаю потоки в Java. Столкнулся с непониманием одного элемента класса Caller, а именно: **Callme target;** - это ссылка на тип класса? Как она работает? Зачем она? Почему тип переменной Callme? Я запутался(

Comment: Callme - класс, target - объект этого класса, создаётся через new Callme();

Comment: Если Вы об этой строке: Callme target = new Callme(); то тут мне все понятно. Я запутался в месте объявления переменных класса Callme, а именно на строке ---> Callme target; <---

Comment: А что именно здесь не понятно? То же самое, что, например, ArrayList list = new ArrayList(); Вместо list можете подставить любое название, за исключением служебных слов java (if, return, volatile и пр.). 
target это просто название объекта класса Callme.

Comment: Опять мимо) Не о той строке, что меня интересует Вы говорите) Я понял о чем Вы: о создании объекта с именем target типа Callme и конструктором класса Callme(). Но я не понял совсем другую строку)

Comment: В классе Caller?

Comment: В объявленном классе Caller который, предшествует классу Example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В прототипе конструктора `Caller(Callme targ)` - вы определяете аргумент `targ` с типом `Callme`, а значит, что при обращении к конструктору `Caller`, нужно будет передавать объект класса `Callme` так:
`new Caller(new Callme())` - где `targ` - будет являться переданным объектом `Callme`.